# Best way to dynamically create a filter object in VueJS with multiple selects

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I've been breaking my head over this for way too long, and start to feel that I'm making this way too difficult to achieve what I want to achieve.

So giving this a try here.

**What do we want to achieve**
Basically, what we want is a repository service in our Vue codebase which allows me to easily fetch data from the server and update the list of data to be displayed.

That service should automatically updates its data whenever we want it to be updated, so that we can easily consume the 'services' by a component.

**What do we have so far**
We created a *Mixin* that we can include in our components.  The idea is that the mixin gives us methods, and holds all responsibilities to update the data.  A grid component would typically also include this mixin, so the data can be updated independently from the view.

This is the code for the repository mixin as we have it so far (only publishing the bits that are important to my question...)

```
var qs = require('qs');
module.exports = {
    data: function() {
        return {
            repository: {
                config: {
                    resource: false,
                    filters: []
                },
                data: [],
                links: null,
                meta: {
                    total: 0
                },
                status: {
                    loading: true,
                    refreshing: true
                },
                filters: {
                },
                paging: {
                    current_page: 1
                },
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        repo: function() {
            var self = this;

            return {
                refresh: function() {
                    if (!self.repository.config.resource) {
                        self.$notify.error('Debug error: resource was not set on the repository');
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        self.repository.status.refreshing = true;
                        self.$http.get(self.repo_query_string).then(
                            (success) => {
                                self.repository.data = success.data.data;
                                self.repository.links = success.data.links;
                                self.repository.meta = success.data.meta;
                                self.repository.status.refreshing = false;
                                self.repository.status.loading = false;
                            },
                            (error) => {

                            }
                        )
                    }
                }

            }
        }

    },
    computed: {
        repo_query_string: function() {
            return '/api/' + this.repository.config.resource + '?' +
                qs.stringify({
                    filter: this.repository.filter,
                    page: this.repository.paging.current_page
                });
        }
    },
    watch: {
        repo_query_string: function() {
            this.repo().refresh();
        }
    },
    mounted: function() {
        this.repo().refresh();

    }
}
```

In our list component (we have multiple views, so we have multiple components that need access to this data source), we can then just use the mixin, and set up config as follows:

```
 module.exports = {
    mixins: [require('../../mixins/repository')],
    data: function() {
        return {
            repository: {
                config: {
                    resource: 'support/tickets/tickets',
                    filters: {
                        //TODO
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    },
    ....
}
```

So, my component will have repository data available in the this.respository.data...  Works great.
Now, we want to add filters to the respository.

Since the resource is set by my list component, my repository has no clue, and also should not have a clue of what fields we can filter on.

Basically, we want something like this:

[image]

In this example, we want the user to basically be able to select types of ticket statusses.  When he doesn't select anything, there should be no filter active, as quickly as he selecte one or more, we want the filter to be applied.

To achieve this, we need to do the following, and this is where I'm looking input for:

1. update filter data:

When we click any of the filters, we need to add or remove the value of the filter in the this.respository.filters.status_id array.
Basically, we want to see this:

```
this.repository.filters.status_id = []
```

would mean there is no active filter for status_id (please note, status_id is chosen by the component, not by the mixin, so how can we dynamically add such a value?

```
this.repository.filters.status_id = ['new', 'in_progress']
```

would mean user only wants to see tickets in status new or in progress.  You get the idea.

So my first question is, how can I easily add / remove items to this object.  The initial state of this.repository.filters is an 'empty object' where status_id is not even set yet...

2/ watch for changes in the filters
Since I don't already set the status_id property on this.repository.filters, I don't think VueJS picks up changes when I add it.  What would be the best way to do this?

3/ and how to send it to the server properly?  This is the final part, but I'm also struggling with how to properly send the updated filters to the server.  It might be best if I just do resource?filters=ENCODED_JSON_OBJECT_GOES_HERE so I can decode it on the server and apply filters accordingly?

I know it seems that I'm asking stuff that has to be around on the net, or on SO, but I still haven't found what I'm looking for, and I was hoping that someone could point me towards a good tutorial on how to achieve this properly.

Because at this time, I'm a bit worried that the solution that we're crafting is too complex to keep it maintainable.  It just looks as something I should be able to do "out of the VueJS box".

Thanks!
David.

Comment: 1 & 2  - Use watchers, or emit events. There might be some logical errors in your code if Watch isn't working.  3 - You can send data via POST method. if you want extra security then use HTTPS. Encoding anything in the client side is as good as leaving the data as it is. Most recommended package for Ajax is Axios. You need not look for anything outside Vuejs.

Comment: Hmm - I don't think I made the question clear enough; I was looking for assistance in how to manage that data object, but I got around to something that works for now.  It just doesn't feel quite as nice.

Comment: i think it safe to not  manage any large data on the client side. It's better to setup a datastructure on the server side and use it as a cache

Comment: ugh - that's exactly what I'm doing.  Not sure I understand how your reply relates to my question?